# Isabelle/HOL proof of normalization of simply typed lambda calculus with pairs

Tags: isabelle, lambda-calculus, theorem-proving

Is there a formalization in Isabelle/HOL of the strong normalization property of the simply typed lambda-calculus **with pairs**?

I am aware of the development in `~~/src/HOL/Proofs/Lambda/StrongNorm.thy`, but that one does not support pairs. (Terms only consist of abstractions, applications, and variables.)

To be specific, by "pairs" I mean that the language should contain constructs such as `Pair x y`, `Fst x`, `Snd x`. And I do not need dependent pairs.

**Background**: The problem came up as part of a larger development where I need strong normalization of a more complex calculus which can, however, be reduced to the strong normalization of the simply typed lambda calculus  with pairs by a suitable embedding.

Comment: A development in another proof assistant (Coq, HOL-light, etc.) might be helpful, too, as a basis for porting it to Isabelle/HOL.

Comment: I hope you have found a solution in the mean time, but in any case, here is a Coq development proving strong normalization of the simply-typed lambda calculus with pairs:
https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/Norm.html

Comment: Thanks. But the problem with that development is:
(a) It leaves out all the steps related to pairs.
(b) It uses the fact that its lambda-calculus uses a deterministic evaluation strategy ("Note that in the forward direction the proof depends on the fact that our language is determinstic. This lemma might still be true for non-deterministic languages, but the proof would be harder!")